# How does Firefox sync really work (when adding new devices)?

Tags: firefox-sync

I'm adding some less frequently used computers to my Firefox sync account. These computers were previously synced using Foxmarks BYOS.

When I started using Firefox Sync, I deleted some old bookmarks.  Later, as I added some other machines, old bookmarks (that still existed on the other machines) were synced back to my main machine.

To prevent that from happening, I wonder if I perhaps need to delete all the bookmarks from new machines before adding them to the Sync account.  But then I worry that it might sync the deletion of all the bookmarks and delete them all from the server and my other machines.

1. Is there any documentation on the exact syncing behavior in the case of adding new devices?
2. Is there any way to monitor progress and sync status?
3. Is there any way to cause a "one way" sync for first time connection (sync server to
   browser only, overwriting everything in the browser?
4. Is there any way to see a list of devices that are associated, and the last time
   they have synced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you set up sync on the new device there is an option to replace all of the data on that computer with the sync data. Or vice versa.